# syntax error when using row_number in sqlite3

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to remove duplicate through `row_number` function based on
 [How to get get Unique Records based on multiple columns from a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816696/how-to-get-get-unique-records-based-on-multiple-columns-from-a-table)
. But Was blocked by a syntax error.
    My use case as below:
[image: this is my table and it named demo]

and my sql as below:

```
select demo.*, 
      row_number() over (partition by id order by creator desc) as rn 
from demo
```

but it tell me:

> near "(": syntax error:

I dont know what happend and I do some search such as [How to use ROW_NUMBER in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847574/how-to-use-row-number-in-sqlite)
. Unfortunately, I still cant figure out what mistake I make. Anything will be appreciate.

Comment: SQLite does not support ROW_NUMBER

Comment: Please use `INSERT`statements to show data, not images.

Comment: SQLite 3.25 and above supports window functions. But can anyone suggest why System.Data.SQLite in c# return the syntax error? Is there anything to configure?

Answer (score 9):

SQLite supports [window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) since [version 3.25](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_25_0.html), so the original query should work now.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, SQLite does not support `row_number()` or other window functions.  You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select d.*
from demo d
where d.creator = (select max(d2.creator) from demo d2 where d2.id = d.id);
```

With an index on `demo(id, creator)` this often has better performance even in databases that do support `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `subquery` instead:

```
select d1.* 
from demo d1
where primarykey = (select d2.primarykey
                    from demo d2
                    where d2.id = d1.id
                    order by d2.creator desc
                    LIMIT 1);
```