# Using rank().over() function in flask-sqlalchemy returns (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask-sqlalchemy to perform a ranking query on a PlayerKillData table, which has 4 columns: ref_id (Primary Key), kill, all_kill and lvl. Specifically, what I want to achieve is to Rank by kill for player on the same lvl and add a Rank column

```
#Columns define in Create Table SQL statement and resolved by reflection at runtime
class PlayerKillData(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "player_kill_data"
```

The following python snippet is that I have tried but no matter how I have tried, it always return sqlite3.OperationalError:

```
subquery = excDB.db.session.query(
PlayerKillData,
excDB.db.func.rank().over(
    order_by = PlayerKillData.kill.desc(),
    partition_by = PlayerKillData.lvl).label('RANK')
)
subquery.all()
```

The SQL statement printed by the error message is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "(": syntax error
[SQL: SELECT player_kill_data.ref_id AS player_kill_data_ref_id, player_kill_data.kill AS player_kill_data_kill, player_kill_data.all_kill AS player_kill_data_all_kill, player_kill_data.lvl AS player_kill_data_lvl, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY player_kill_data.lvl ORDER BY player_kill_data.kill DESC) AS "RANK"
FROM player_kill_data]
```

I have also tried running the SQL statement directly using Db Browser for SQLite and it returned the table successfully without any error.

I am really puzzled by this and would like any help I can get to solve this.

Comment: what version of sqlite?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53593125/6560549

Comment: Sqlalchemy is using pysqlite driver, still searching for sqlite version number. DB Browser supports sqlite 3.27.2

Answer (score 1):

Your version of SQLite might be smaller than `3.25.0`.

As mentionned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/53593125/6560549) and confirmed in the [Release History of SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html), SQLite supports window function (RANK() OVER ...) since version `3.25.0`, which was released on 2018-09-15.

To check your version of SQLite in python:

```
import sqlite3
print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)
# returns '3.22.0' for me
```

If many people work on the same codebase and you'd like to have a more explicit error message for other developers, you can assert:

```
assert sqlite3.sqlite_version_info >= (3,25,0), """sqlite3 version must be >= 3.25.0 because that's when it started to support window functions"""
```