# Partitioned Using Multiple Column

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to partitioned by tables based on day and range. So my table has department field so i want to create partition like this :

```
2023-06-01 , Dep Range (1-100)
2023-06-01 , Dep Range (101-200)
2023-06-01 , Dep Range (201-300)
2023-06-02 , Dep Range (1-100)
2023-06-02 , Dep Range (101-200)
2023-06-02 , Dep Range (201-300)
... So on
```

How i can do that, currently i am doing via data like this :

```
 CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION dailyPartitionFunction (date)
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (
    '2023-06-01', '2023-06-02'....
);
```

Comment: That seems like *far* too many partitions. A table can have at most 15,000 partitions, but [Microsoft themselves state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16) that at 1,000 partitions it would start to have *"implications on memory, partitioned index operations, DBCC commands, and queries."* You would hit 1,000 partitions in *less* than a year.

Comment: @ThomA I am holding data for 15 days only for Department range from 1 to 1000, so i think it will be fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table partitioning using 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671161/table-partitioning-using-2-columns)

Comment: Do it on a computed column `DateAndDeptBlock AS (CONVERT(varchar(10), Date, 103) + CASE WHEN Dep > 0 AND Dep <= 100 THEN 1 WHEN ...) PERSISTED`

Comment: You might want to think about why you want partitioning in the first place. It's not a performance help ususally, it's mainly for managing bulk insertion and deletion.